# Azure SQL Database v12 column type change

Tags: azure-sql-database

I was wondering if anyone can sanity-check an approach for changing column types in an Azure SQL Database v12. We'd like to convert some varchar columns to support unicode, so since the v12 upgrade, this seems to be the most straightforward approach:

```
ALTER TABLE table1 ALTER COLUMN column1 nvarchar(max) NULL WITH (ONLINE=ON);
ALTER TABLE table1 ALTER COLUMN column2 nvarchar(max) NULL WITH (ONLINE=ON);
```

We held-off on making this before v12 upgrade so that we could use the new "ONLINE=ON" switch...hoping to avoid the overhead of moving all of the rows (billions of them) from an old table (with old column types) to a new table (with the new nvarchar types), then renaming things at the end.

As the new approach all feels "too easy", I wanted to ask if I'm missing something obvious. Can multiple alter columns for the same table be bundled into the same command (and if so, is that better than tweaking the table multiple times)?

We can dial-up the Pricing Tier during the upgrade, and schedule it to run during the quietest overnight window. Beyond that, thanks, in advance, to the community for any other advice that might help!

Comment: Nvarchar takes up twice the space ,further few downsides i could see for a clustered index table or a table with non clustered indexes,additional space increase operation might lead to fragmentation (due to which you may want to rebuild indexes) plus huge transaction log growth which is restricted in azure as per you DB tier.Further you cant run mutiple tables alter the way you are trying,since those will run one by one and each one will hold a schema lock.so i suggest  you go with first option of creating a table with out indexes or constraints and then dumping data and later creating indexes

Comment: I'm concerned about the schema lock comment...wasn't that the problem that "WITH (ONLINE=ON)" was built to solve?

Comment: From BOL,i could see The locking strategy during an alter column online operation follows the same locking pattern used for online index build. which means exclusive lock will be obtained for initially and at ending ,though this locks are very short lived,it depends on usage...BOL link :https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190273.aspx  .The page i linked have Good overview on restrcitions too

Comment: Its Good to test those restrictions by creating a table in same database with some dummy data